# Modify char *array[x][y]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

How can I modify (increase ASCII value) each char in a two dimensional array of `char *`?

I have this code now:

```
int riadky = 2;
int stlpce = 7;

char* x[riadky][stlpce];

int i,j;
for ( i = 0; i < riadky; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < stlpce; j++)
        x[i][j] = "test";

x[0][1] = "something";

for ( i = 0; i < riadky; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < stlpce; j++){
        printf("%s ", x[i][j]);
    }
        printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");

char * temp;
for ( i = 0; i < riadky; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < stlpce; j++) {
        for (temp= x[i][j]; *temp; temp++) {
            (*temp)++;            //segmentation fault
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, it segfaults on the line with the comment.

---

I try this,  but still...  segmentation falult

```
char ***alloc_array(int x, int y) {
    char ***a = calloc(x, sizeof(char **));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i != x; i++) {
        a[i] = calloc(y, sizeof(char *));
    }
    return a;
}

int main() {

    int riadky = 3;
    int stlpce = 7;
    char ***x = alloc_array(riadky, stlpce);

    int i,j;
    for ( i = 0; i < riadky; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < stlpce; j++){
            strcpy(x[i][j],"asdasd");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code to see what is going on with your code?

Comment: no, bcs I don't have any IDE, only notepad + terminal

Comment: Are you trying to increase each letter in each of the strings pointed to by `x`, or just the first letter of each string?

Comment: Use temporary printf calls to see what values you are getting around the line causing the seg fault

Comment: every letter of each string

Comment: To clarify @user3121023, when you assign `x[i][j] = 'test'`, you're referring to a static string, which is (depending on your compiler) going to be the *same string* for every instance of your loop, making this difficult to debug.  You should `malloc()` a string for each entry instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> for ( i = 0; i < riadky; i++)
>   for (j = 0; j < stlpce; j++)
>     x[i][j] = "test";
>
> x[0][1] = "something";
> ```

You are initializing your pointers to point to string literals. The compiler is allowed (but not required to) place string literals in read-only memory. An attempt to modify one of them is likely to result in a segmentation fault.

You need to allocate *dynamic* memory for your strings:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...

for (...) {
  for (...) {
    x[i][j] = malloc (strlen (somestring)+1);
    if (x[i][j]) {
      strcpy (x[i][j], somestring);
    } else {
      /* Allocation error */
    }
```

where `somestring` is a string literal or a variable containing the string you want to store. If you later need to store larger strings, you will have to `realloc()` your pointers. Don't forget to `free()` your pointers when you are done using them.

I noticed that you have edited your post to include another attempt at the same problem, this time using dynamically allocated arrays rather than static arrays. But you still haven't allocated any memory for the actual strings, just an array of pointers. My answer should work unchanged for *both* versions of your code.